# regexp_replace in postgres keep only desired with single space

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, postgres-9.6

What i'd like is to turn a string like this;

`10  -  15 st.  pan,cras`

to

`10 - 15 ST PANCRAS`

I get most of the way with

```
 `select upper(regexp_replace('10  -  15 st.  pan,cras', '[^a-zA-Z 0-9-]', '', 'g'));`
```

But i can't seem to remove the double spaces around the number. I've tried, adding an extra space in the expression;

```
 `select upper(regexp_replace('10  -  15 st.  pan,cras', '[^a-zA-Z  0-9-]', '', 'g'));`
```

But no difference in outcome. I'm using `regexp_replace` as i find the `substring` syntax harder to follow. On 9.6 string is stored in `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add space collapsing to only one expression, like this:

```
t=# select regexp_replace('q            q','( ){1,}',' ','g');
 regexp_replace
----------------
 q q
(1 row)
```

It replaces with single space if finds one or more following spaces in a row.

so in your case will be

```
t=# select regexp_replace(upper(regexp_replace('10  -  15 st.  pan,cras', '[^a-zA-Z 0-9-]', '', 'g')),'( ){1,}',' ','g');
   regexp_replace
--------------------
 10 - 15 ST PANCRAS
(1 row)
```

Comment: yes, a short instructions are in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html